# How to avoid an error in this Python code?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to fix this problem. I'm new in Python.

Code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss.linux import MSS as mss
from PIL import Image
import time
import pyautogui as pg
import imutils
import mss
import numpy
import pyautogui

avarage = [0, ]
poplovok = cv2.imread('poplovok.png')
w, h = poplovok.shape[::-1]

base_screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1152, 880))
base_screen.save('/Users/vk/PycharmProject/bototest/base_screen.png')
img_rgb = cv2.imread('base_screen.png')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, poplovok, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
loc = np.where(res >= 0.7)
for i in range(40):
    try:
        clean_screen = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, x + w, y + h))
        mean = np.mean(clean_screen)
        dif = avarage[-1] - mean
        print(avarage[-1] - mean)
    except:
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            x = int(pt[0])
            y = int(pt[1])
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you describe what you are trying to do, and how this particular code is failing (error messages, for example)

Comment: seem poplovok.shape have more than 2 elements, had you tried to save poplovok.shape in a variable and look it??

Comment: `poplovok.shape` returns 3 values tuple which is `height, width, channels`. Modify your code to `_, w, h = poplovok.shape[::-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image `poplovok.png` has more than 2 dimensions. To care about only width and height, and ignore the others, use:

```
w, h, *_ = poplovok.shape[::-1]
```

The `_` implies you do not care about the variable, and `*` slurps all the remaining dimensions to `_`.